# Why is the image chosen from gallery with bigger size not showing?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-bitmap, android-image

```
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        imageuri = data.data
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageuri)
        try {
            if(bitmap != null){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Not empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                imageView?.setImageURI(imageuri)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "It is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            displayExceptionMessage(e.message)
        }

    }
```

Other images with a size of 2MB and below are loading but when it is higher than 2MB it is not displaying. Can someone tell the mistake? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that bitmap==null ?

Comment: @blackapps sorry i'm newbie, but could you tell me which part are you pertaining to?

Comment: `bitmap = MediaStore.Im..........`. You assigned a value to bitmap. But which value did it get? I suggested to check if the value of bitmap is null. If so you could display a toast. And if so i will tell you why it became null. Please add that code also here.

Comment: You should also add a Toast to the catch block of the IOException as you should inform the user about such things. Please update your code here.

Comment: @blackapps i did what you said. And this is what i received when choosing the image.

W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3120x4160, max=4096x4096)
I/chatty: uid=10196(com.example.imageclassification) RenderThread identical 1 line
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3120x4160, max=4096x4096)
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x797d8ec000,api=1)
D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = com.color.internal.widget.ColorToastLayout{fb64156 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-178,62 #c0204f9 oppo:id/color_toast_layout}

Comment: `And this is what i received when choosing the image. ` Not at choosing but with the statement that assigns the bitmap to that image view. Right?

Comment: And which toast do you see?

Comment: You changed your code. You are not using that bitmap anymore. You did not report that. Tell which statement causes that message.

Comment: @blackapps is this the toast?

D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false

Comment: ????? You added two Toast() statements to your code. I only asked which of the two comes/came up. You should tell what happens. And you still did not tell if bitmap was null although it was my first question three hours ago.

Comment: `"Not empty"` You mean not null. Empty is something different. And what is not null? `"Bitmap==null"` would be more informative.

Comment: @blackapps thanks, Glide solved the issue :D thank you btw.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to read with bitmap.
You can do like this :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) 
 {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    imageuri = data.data
    try {
   
        imageView!!.setImageUri(imageuri)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Comment: If it is, please use Glide or Picasso library for loading image

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
      imageView?.let {
        Glide.with(this)
        .load(imageuri)
        .into(it)}
```